# Change cart item prices based on custom cart item data in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-fields

currently i create a form in product single page so that customer can enter  height and width of the product . So the product price vary based on the entered height and width .

I created this form in

> woocommerce->single-product->add-to-cart->simple.php

Before modification  the form is

```
<form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <?php
        /**
         * @since 2.1.0.
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' );

        /**
         * @since 3.0.0.
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );

        woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
            'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
            'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
            'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
        ) );

        /**
         * @since 3.0.0.
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );
    ?>

    <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

    <?php
        /**
         * @since 2.1.0.
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' );
    ?>
</form>
```

After modification form is

```
<form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <p>width  <input type="text" name="new-width" class="new-width"></p>
    <p>Height <input type="text" name="new-height" class="new-height"></p>
        <?php
            /**
             * @since 2.1.0.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' );

            /**
             * @since 3.0.0.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );

            woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
                'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
                'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
            ) );

            /**
             * @since 3.0.0.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );
        ?>

        <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

        <?php
            /**
             * @since 2.1.0.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' );
        ?>
    </form>
```

After this i used   the following code and for testing pupose i set value to 30 . But it is not working . what i missed  ?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item' , 'set_woo_prices');

function set_woo_prices( $woo_data ) {

  if(isset( $_POST['new-width']))  { $woo_data['new-width'] =$_POST['new-width']; }
  if(isset( $_POST['new-height'])) { $woo_data['new-height'] =$_POST['new-height']; }
  if( $_POST['new-width'] !=="" && $_POST['new-height']!=="" ){

     $woo_data['data']->set_price( "30" ); 
    }
     return $woo_data;

}
```

Please advice . My aim is to change product price based on user entered width and height .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use 2 different hooks:

- The first one just as yours without trying to change the price in it.
- The second one where you will change your cart item price

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'add_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function add_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {

    if( isset( $_POST['new-width'] ) )
        $cart_item_data['new-width'] = $_POST['new-width'];
    if(isset( $_POST['new-height'] ) )
       $cart_item_data['new-height'] = $_POST['new-height'];

    return $cart_item_data;
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_custom_cart_item_price', 20, 1 );
function set_custom_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // First loop to check if product 11 is in cart
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( isset($cart_item['new-width']) && isset($cart_item['new-height']) 
        && ! empty($cart_item['new-width']) && ! empty($cart_item['new-height']) )
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( '30' );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works

Comment: (1) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QZDs0iBPIBEaGGIfunHGsJkLukEqwnPZ    (2) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jLzUkUmZALC7JRpVLjDMzAgI3oF_wmv0

Comment: (3) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1082NdvMe7_lCUkESaDYIRqSL14rG-5GK  please check all these image .

Comment: @ Mini cart is another thing and another question, as it's Ajax driven and needs to use related updated cart fragments to get refreshed correctly. It depends on your theme and customizations too. So this is much more complicated to handle… In Here I am just answering this question and I have maid your code working, or not?

Comment: it is 100% working friend . Thanks for your support . i will check this woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session

Comment: @abilasher I have never used this hook yet …