# How to get WooCommerce cart item data array by its key?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a key like `$cart_item_key = f7ebf06b2c9ff23e2efe046992eb949c`

By default this key has an array (`WC->cart->get_cart()`)

```
Array ( [f7ebf06b2c9ff23e2efe046992eb949c] =>
Array ( [unique_key] => 6bf1cd893cfb6ea388076bc99a08891a
        [thwepof_options] =>
Array ( [order_date] =>
Array ( [name] => order_date
        [value] => 06-02-2018, monday
        [label] => Order date [options] => ) )
        [key] => f7ebf06b2c9ff23e2efe046992eb949c
        [product_id] => 770
        [variation_id] => 771
        [variation] => Array ( )
        [quantity] => 1
        ) ) )
```

I didn't found any function in the [WooCommerce documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/) which helps me to solve this problem.

Originally this is how Woocommerce calls the cart items, but I filtered those keys which I need for the future development:

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
```

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188365/how-to-retrieve-cart-item-data-with-woocommerce) on the forum but none of these worked.

Answer (score 10):

There is a method in cart object call `get_cart_item( $item_key )`, if you pass the `$cart_item_key` as method argument you'll get the item data. For more details check the source https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#615-623

```
WC()->cart->get_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw. I found a solution: the `$cart_item` is that key which I store. So:

```
if($cart_item_key == $cart_item) {
//TODO
}
```